# Conditional aggregation referencing table instead of manual entry

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, pivot

I asked a question previously on conditional aggregation.  [SQL Transform Crosstab Pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37290046/sql-transform-crosstab-pivot-data) and the answer was great!  However, I need to expand on this.

The solution at the time was the following query:

```
SELECT
    Item,
    [X] = MAX(CASE WHEN [Columns] = 'X' THEN Result END),
    [Y] = MAX(CASE WHEN [Columns] = 'Y' THEN Result END),
    [Z] = MAX(CASE WHEN [Columns] = 'Z' THEN Result END)
FROM thisTable
GROUP BY Item
```

**Question:** I now have a table `TEST` with W, X, Y, Z in rows.  Instead of adding another line (`[W] = MAX(CASE WHEN [Columns] = 'W' THEN Result END)`) to the query, can the query above be re-written to refer to the table for the values?

The reason is because I anticipate that there will more than just W, X, Y, Z and want to avoid adding more lines to this query in the future.

Comment: you should use a dynamic pivot.[This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18657214/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-over-5-columns?rq=1) might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to stay with conditional aggregation you can create your query dynamically like this.

```
DECLARE @Columns NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  @Columns = STUFF((
    SELECT  ',' + CONCAT(QUOTENAME([Columns]), ' = MAX(CASE WHEN [Columns] = ''', [Columns], ''' THEN Result END)')
    FROM    thisTable
    GROUP BY [Columns] -- distinct
    ORDER BY [Columns] -- order column names
    FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 1, '')

SET @Sql = N'
    SELECT  Item,
            ' + @Columns + '
    FROM    thisTable
    GROUP BY Item
'
EXEC(@Sql)
```

if you want to use DESCRIPTION from TEST as column name you could use this.

```
SELECT  @Columns = STUFF((
    SELECT  ',' + CONCAT(QUOTENAME([Description]), ' = MAX(CASE WHEN [Columns] = ''', [Columns], ''' THEN Result END)')
    FROM    TEST
    FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 1, '')
```

Comment: Nice, this appears to do what I want.  However, I have a table `TEST` with the descriptions of these columns instead of values.  I tried joining this test table in the first SELECT statement to see if I can get the column description instead, but got an error...any ideas how I can join this `TEST` table?

Comment: can you show my what you have now? or at least the table schemas

Comment: The result has the columns Item, W, X, Y, Z.  My `TEST` table has 2 columns: Column, Description.  Column has 4 rows, W, X, Y, Z and Description has 4 rows, Description1, Description2, Description3, Description4.  I'm trying to get the resulting table to show the Description in the column instead of W, X, Y, Z in the original query.

Comment: you might be able to just change the @Columns query to this.. `SELECT  @Columns = STUFF((
 SELECT ',' + CONCAT(QUOTENAME([Description]), ' = MAX(CASE WHEN [Columns] = ''', [Columns], ''' THEN Result END)')
 FROM TEST
 FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 1, '')`

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!