# Is PIVOT the right command

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a table imported form a different application the format of the import is

```
ID1 Variable1   value 
ID1 Variable2   value
ID1 Variable3   value
ID2 Variable1   value 
ID2 Variable2   value
ID2 Variable3   value
ID3 Variable1   value 
ID3 Variable2   value
ID3 Variable3   value
```

I need to change the format so that it is as below

```
[ID]    [Variable1] [Variable2] [Variable3]
ID1     value       value       value
ID2     value       value       value
ID3     value       value       value
```

When I look this up on the internet PIVOT is the option suggested is this the correct approach as I don’t want to aggregate any value.

I have not been able to convert any of the examples that I have seen into code this prompted me to ask Is PIVOT the right command.

Comment: PIVOT combines all the values for a specific `ID,Variable` combination to one value so you *have* to use an aggregate function even if it's `MAX`

Comment: Ref: PIVOT carries out an aggregation and merges possible multiple rows into a single row in the output.  re: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16#basic-pivot-example

Comment: You might also think of PIVOT as a complex series of SELECT CASE statements which are much more challenging to maintain and understand.

Comment: My rule of thumb is if you mention pivot, it's not the right choice. The syntax is ugly and impossible to remember. Read about conditional aggregation and do your pivots manually. See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38109330/conditional-aggregation-referencing-table-instead-of-manual-entry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (ID VARCHAR(3), Variable VARCHAR(10), Value VARCHAR(5));
INSERT INTO @Table (ID, Variable, Value) VALUES
('ID1', 'Variable1', 'value'),  ('ID1', 'Variable2', 'value'), ('ID1', 'Variable3', 'value'), ('ID2', 'Variable1', 'value'),  
('ID2', 'Variable2', 'value'), ('ID2', 'Variable3', 'value'), ('ID3', 'Variable1', 'value'),  ('ID3', 'Variable2', 'value'), 
('ID3', 'Variable3', 'value');

SELECT *
  FROM @Table
  PIVOT (
         MAX(Value) FOR Variable IN (Variable1, Variable2, Variable3)
        ) p;
```

| ID | Variable1 | Variable2 | Variable3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | value | value | value |
| ID2 | value | value | value |
| ID3 | value | value | value |

`PIVOT` requires an aggregate. Given your values are all `[N]VARCHAR` it doesn't really matter if we use MIN or MAX. In order to have a column returned from the `PIVOT` it must be included in the `FOR`. Adding `, Variable4` would include another column with `NULL` values, as there aren't any in the table. Removing `, Variable3` would remove that column, ignoring any values present for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a 3-dimensional join:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.value AS Variable1, t2.value AS Variable2, t3.value AS Variable3
FROM yourtable t1
JOIN yourtable t2
ON t1.ID = t2.ID
JOIN yourtable t3
ON t2.ID = t3.ID
WHERE t1.Variable = 'Variable1' AND
      t2.Variable = 'Variable2' AND
      t3.Variable = 'Variable3'
```

This way, you join together 3 records for each row, force t1 to be of Variable1, t2 to be of Variable2, t3 to be of Variable3. And you have no aggregation at play. You simply read all the values as they are and name them as Variable1, Variable2 and Variable3 for clarity's sake.

However, the query above assumes that for each ID you have a Variable1, a Variable2 and a Variable3. If you cannot make that assumption, then you will need to use outer joins. But, since your question's example does not suggest this being possible, this answer for the time being will assume that each tuple will have all of the 3 components existent.